# android/java sockets help

Tags: java, android, sockets

Here is my goal. I am designing a server that will spit out data every second. I need to also design a client (on android) that will connect to that server and gather the data that is being sent by the server. I have already wrote up some code for this in java and for the android. However, my experience with java and android is very minimal. I have been having a lot of difficulty with this but have started making progress. **I was wondering if everyone could take a look at my code and give some tips on how to best perform this design.**

The server will just be constantly spitting out data and the client will connect to the server and then start gathering the data that is being sent.

The data that is being sent is not important. Right now it will just be something random for testing.

Thanks in advance!

```
THE JAVA SERVER

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

import java.net.ServerSocket;

import java.net.Socket;





public class SmartServerSocket {

    private ServerSocket server;

    private int port = 7777;



    public SmartServerSocket() {

        try {

            server = new ServerSocket(port);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SmartServerSocket smart = new SmartServerSocket();

        smart.handleConnection();

    }

    public void handleConnection() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Waiting for client message...");

        while (true) {

            try {

                Socket socket = server.accept();

                new ConnectionHandler(socket);

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

    }

}

class ConnectionHandler implements Runnable {

    private Socket socket;

    public ConnectionHandler(Socket socket) {

        this.socket = socket;

        Thread t = new Thread(this);

        t.start();

    }

    public void run() {

        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

        int test = 0;

        try {

            while(true)

            {

                oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                oos.writeObject(Integer.toString(test));

                test++;

                System.out.println("Waiting for client message...");

            } 

        } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            try {

                    oos.close();

                    socket.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }



            }

        }

    }




THE ANDROID CLIENT
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

//import android.app.Activity;

public class ConnectDevice implements Runnable {
    public void run(){
        try {
            System.out.println("test1");
            //InetAddress host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("THEIPADDRESS");
            Socket socket = new Socket(host.getHostName(), 7777);
            System.out.println("test2");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("test3");
            String message = (String) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("test4");    
            System.out.println("Message: " + message);

            ois.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Apache Mina to handle my game's connection. You should take a look on it. It have really made my life easier.

Comment: i would, but the only reason i am doing this is to create a testing method for the application i am making for the android that is for a project. The project will be using a wifly board to connect to the android, so apache will probably not be an option at that point. I am trying to make it as close to the wifly connection as possible. I was just wanting some tips on the basics of java sockets and android. Thanks.